# Neverending cycle with fscanf in C

Tags: c

Hello I am having a problem with reading a binary file with `fscanf`, the values aren't being stored and the cycle while is infinite

Here's my code

```
int main(){
FILE *reads=fopen("E1.bin", "rb");;
int temp=0,temp1=0,temp2=0;

if (reads==NULL) {
    printf("Error");
    return 0;
}
else {
    while((fscanf(reads,"%d %d %d", temp, temp1, temp2))!= EOF){
        printf("%d -- %d -- %d\n",temp, temp1, temp2);
    }
}
fclose(reads);
return 0;
```

}

This keeps returning "0 -- 0 -- 0"

Comment: Use `fscanf()` for a text file, [`fread()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fread.html) for a binary file.

Comment: Look at the [manual page for `fscanf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and read the section about RETURN VALUE. Actually, you should probably read the whole thing. But as pmg said, you don't want to use it for binary files. I'm also a little surprised it didn't segfault since you didn't pass the addresses of the temp variables.

Comment: What will your code do when `fscanf` can't convert the input for one of the `%d` format and it gets stuck in the input buffer?  `!= EOF` is not what you should be checking but `== 3`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, after changing from fscanf() to fread() i can read it properly, although it's only reading the first line

Comment: "it's only reading the first line" ... it's a binary file: there are no lines. Post another question with your new code and example input and expected output.

Comment: This could be an [XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fscanf(reads,"%d %d %d", temp, temp1, temp2` is expected to return 3, 2, 1, 0 or `EOF`.

Below code only stops when `EOF` returned.

```
while((fscanf(reads,"%d %d %d", temp, temp1, temp2))!= EOF){
    printf("%d -- %d -- %d\n",temp, temp1, temp2);
}
```

Thus when `fscanf()` returns 0,1,2 code is erranly printing old  data.  In those cases, the non-numeric text is not read and is used in the next input function.  Yet since the next input function looks again for numeric text, the cycle repeats - infinite loop.

---

Certainly reading a `.bin` file is not text based as expected with `fscanf()` and code was stuck trying to read numeric text.

With a binary file, I'd expect:

```
int t[3];
while (fread(t, sizeof t[0], 3, reads) == 3) {
  printf("%d -- %d -- %d\n",t[0], t[1], t[2]);
}
```

---

If file really is text, compare against 3, not `EOF`.

```
while((fscanf(reads,"%d %d %d", temp, temp1, temp2)) == 3){
    printf("%d -- %d -- %d\n",temp, temp1, temp2);
}
```